Possible to make a roche limit simulation?
I would like to create a simulation of the Roche Limit. I have already given it a crack using simulation nodes but it's not ideal. I'm currently using SpaceSim to visualize it.

But I want the rendering power and familiarity of Blender.
My current geometry node tree is pretty messy so I shall just outline the logic.

Spawn grid of points in sphere volume
All points experience a constant attraction to center of sphere
If two points get too close they move away from each other
A second sphere (attractor) is placed a distance away. I then calculate the pull of gravity of this sphere and subtract the pull of the original sphere (Tidal Force)
I can then move the attractor closer which creates the desired effect. But it like pulses, it doesn't orbit, and it doesn't form a ring/sphere.


Is there any way to create a decent roche limit sim?

A stupid question perhaps: is the original sphere (split in points if I understand correctly) orbiting around the second sphere (the attractor) ? From your bottom picture, it seems that only centripetal forces are acting. To debug, you can check that if the attractor is "far away", the point cloud should orbit at constant radius. More celestial physics than Blender usage however...
